# Cannot pass encrypted Text from C# to C++ and opposite

Tags: c#, c++, string, dllimport

I have a c++ dll includes AES encryption , the function has two input :

1. string : to crypt with AES
2. string : output of encryption

**Here's the external function :**

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void aes_crypter(const char* string_in , wchar_t* string_out);
void aes_crypter(const char* string_in , wchar_t* string_out)
{
    std::string X_KEY = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123412";
    std::string X_PSS = "612345601234512";

    //////// convert input text to LPCWSTR
    const wchar_t* inputtext = convertCharArrayToLPCWSTR(string_in);

    //////// convert LPCWSTR to string [const to string result wrong ]
    std::wstring ws(inputtext);   
    std::string str(ws.begin(), ws.end());

    //////// Encrypt
    auto encr = encrypt(str, key, X_PSS);

    //////// Convert and Return to Output String
    std::wstring widestr = std::wstring(encr.begin(), encr.end()); 
    const wchar_t* output_crypt = widestr.c_str(); /// CONVERT STD TO WCHAR
    swprintf(string_out, 4096,output_crypt);

}
```

**Code works fine , the problem is in my C# app :**

Here's Importing Function Code :

```
[DllImport("simpleAES.dll",
CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
private static extern void aes_crypter(string string_in, StringBuilder string_out);
```

**ISSUES :**

- If I set CharSet to ANSI , input string works fine , in c++ returns right
  But output string returns wrong only one character !
- If I set CharSet to UNICODE, input string returns wrong and only one character.
  But output string returns right !

Where I made a mistake ? How can I fix it ?

Comment: Your character set is Ansi which is one byte characters.  You are using wide character which are two bytes.

Comment: @jdweng there's anyway to pass them in one function ? only way is to making two function one with ANSI one with Unicode ?

Comment: There are a few things wrong.  IN c++ char* string_in is a pointer to a byte[] object terminated with a '\0'.  It is not a c# string.  A string in C# is a class object.  A c++ wchar_t is equivalent to a pointer to a c# int16[].  Not a string builder which in c# is a class object.

Comment: You can set `MarshalAs` per parameter.

Comment: @Aybe can you write it as a code example then i can mark it as answer. thank you

Comment: See some examples here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshaling-for-strings#cpcondefaultmarshalingforstringsanchor5

Comment: This looks like XY problem. It's not clear why C# is asking C++ to run AES, and what your actual goal is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::string` and `std::wstring` cannot be copied to each other using `std::copy` and related methods, except when the source contains ASCII characters. That's not the case here. Although you are staring with ASCII, the encrypted text will be in binary, it's neither ASCII nor Unicode.

You could copy the `std::wstring` in binary in to `std::string`. But I think that won't help you here, because `encrypt` seems to expect null-ternminated string.

Instead you can convert UTF16 to UTF8 and back:

```
#include <string>
#include <codecvt>

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
bool aes_crypter(const wchar_t* string_in, BYTE* data, int &datalen)
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>, wchar_t> convert;
    std::string utf8 = convert.to_bytes(string_in);

    std::string encr = encrypt(utf8, X_KEY, X_PSS);
    datalen = encr.size();
    if(datalen > 4096)
        return false;

    memcpy(data, &encr[0], datalen);
    return true;
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
void aes_decrypter(const BYTE *data, int datalen, wchar_t* string_out)
{
    std::string utf8 = decrypt(data, datalen, X_KEY, X_PSS);
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>, wchar_t> convert;
    std::wstring utf16 = convert.from_bytes(utf8);
    wcscpy_s(string_out, 4096, utf16.c_str());
}
```

Your C# application will receive encrypted binary `data`, of some length `datalen`

```
["simpleAES.dll",
CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern bool aes_crypter(string input, IntPtr data, ref int datalen);

["simpleAES.dll",
CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern bool aes_decrypter(IntPtr data, int datalen, StringBuilder sb);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int datalen = 0;
    IntPtr data = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(4096);
    if (aes_crypter("1234", data, ref datalen))
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(4096);
        aes_decrypter(data, datalen, sb);
        string recover = sb.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(recover);
    }
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(data);
}
```

You should also pass the size for `StringBuilder` instead of assuming it is `4096`

Note that in C++, the `c_str()` method will look for `NUL` character and tries to return a null-terminated string. But your encrypt function creates binary data which could have many zeros in the middle.

You can make things easier if you encrypt function accepts binary input, and outputs `std::vector<BYTE>` instead of `std::string`. Example

```
std::vector<BYTE> encrypt(binary_data_to_encrypt, datalen, X_KEY, X_PSS);
```